# Буква Ф в начале слова

Tags: орфоэпия

Были ли раньше в русском языке слова, начинающиеся на букву Ф?

А слова, содержащие в себе букву Ф?

Почему?

Comment: Раньше... Это когда?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не было такого звука в славянском. Все эти слова заимствованные, прежде всего - из греческого. А все индоевропейские Ф перешли в праславянском в П или (много реже) Х/ХВ. 
Почитайте хотя бы "Слово о словах" Льва Успенского.

Comment: Звук Ф на Руси был всегда!

Успенский это подтверждает: "Что же получается? Видимо, русский язык по какой-то причине вовсе не знает и не употребляет звука «ф»?
Ничего подобного... Звук «ф» в нашем языке ничуть не менее обычен, чем во многих других".

Comment: Место, где Успенский это "подтверждает", можете привести?  

Звук, если был, то только как аллофон В.

Comment: Я Вам привел это место у Успенского!
"Что же получается? Видимо, русский язык по какой-то причине вовсе не знает и не употребляет звука «ф»? Ничего подобного... Звук «ф» в нашем языке ничуть не менее обычен, чем во многих других".

Comment: >Я Вам привел это место у Успенского!   
  
И что? Дальше там ничего нет?  )))

Кстати, Федя, вы русский от прасвлявянского отличаете?

Answer (score 2):

Может быть, вам покажутся интересными следующие сведения.

А) Когда в 12 веке утратились редуцированные гласные Ь и Ъ, звонкие согласные на конце слова и перед глухими согласными стали оглушаться: дубъ - дуп, бровь - брофь, также вере(ф)ка, в(ф)ход.   Так в языке появляются два новых звука - ф и фь. До этого звук ф в русском языке был только в заимствованных греческих словах: Федор, Феодосий, Фекла.

Б) В словах: второй, втулка, всякий  пишется сочетание ВТ, ВС. Написание разных по звонкости-глухости согласных в начале исконно русских слов  может показаться странным, но это связано с особым положение буквы Ф.

Буква Ф в русском языке встречается  только в заимствованных словах, так как в древнерусском языке не было соответствующего звука Ф, который появился  только после падения редуцированных гласных, например: въход –  в(ф)ход. Буква Ф  заимствована из греческой алфавита при создании русской письменности при Кирилле и Мефодии. Еще двести лет назад слова с этой буквой  не часто встречались в русском языке, но сейчас появилось и русифицировалось много таких корней. Тем не менее,  буква Ф по-прежнему остается самой редкой.

Comment: Спасибо! Я понял Ваш комментарий. Он хорош!

У меня речь шла о том, что в русском языке звук Ф был всегда, но он не обозначался графически (вероятно, не было такой буквы).

Об этом и рассказывает Лев Успенский в приведенной мной цитате.

Comment: В южно-русских говорах "в" билабиальное, т.е. это не [v], а [w] = короткое "у". Поэтому в ситуациях оглушения оно не превращается в "ф", а сохраняется как короткое"у". Значит в некоторых диалектах звук "ф" так и не появился.

Comment: >У меня речь шла о том, что в русском языке    
   
С какого времени вы начинаете отсчет "русского языка"?  
И что называете звуком?  
Я вам дал вполне исчерпывающую формулировку.   
"Звук" Ф мог сущестовать только как позиционный аллофон фонемы В.  
  
>В южно-русских говорах "в" билабиальное, т.е. это не [v]  
  
Абсолютно верно. Правда, не уверен, что Федя это оценит.)))

Comment: Комментарию Бегемотуса даю хорошую оценку!
Молодец!
Однако выскажу свою точку зрения.
И поправьте, если ошибусь:
Наши предки в общении использовали звук "Ф", не заморачиваясь на то, есть ли она у них в алфавите. 

Дело в том, что я сторонник следующей теории:
В речи среднего человека (при прочих естественных условиях) определенные звуки (фонемы) не могут не существовать в силу самого строения речевого аппарата.

Comment: Если не насиловать этот аппарат, как, скажем, это происходит во французском, английском произношении (да и почти во всех не славянских языках) любому человеку наиболее естественно произносить следующие, как я их называю, "чистые акценты" (по-вашему - звуки или фонемы): А, О, У, Е, И, Э, Ю, Я, Б, Г, Д, Ж, З, Г, Л, М, Р и т.д.

Есть и менее "акцентно чистые", но так же вполне употребимые (вы их назовете глухими и что-то в этом роде): Ш, К, В, С, Н, П, Т, Ф, Х и др.

Comment: Как раз-то русский язык, по моему наблюдению, и является наиболее естественным для такого произношения. Объясняется это простором и широтой окружавшей его столетиями Природы. Отсюда, кстати, и особенности характера россиян. 
Сама буква "Ф" (точнее - звук "Ф") -  числится в списке естественно-произносимых звуков.

Answer (score 0):

Когда Иероним писал глаголицу для Иллирии в 5 веке (по официальной истории), а Иллирия была поделена на две части в одной из них жили греки, а в другой - по нынешнему названию славяне. И он добавил к славянским буквам греческие, чтоб греки и славяне могли писать этим письмом. Потом Кирилл начал добавлять греческие буквы, но для того, чтоб не переводить некоторые слова на русский. Так что многие буквы, которые они добавили не нужны, хотя благодаря Петру и большевикам мы избавились от большинства ненужных букв (из плохого: большевики токмо правописание изменили). А буква Ф тем более не нужна, потому что это П с придыханием, а в русском говоре нет придыханий. И к стати я ввёл церковно-славянское название буквы Ф (Ферт) в переводчик и перевелось как "приносить" (но возможно это просто совпадение). Если что, могу скрин скинуть на почту.

Comment: Я вас огорчу. Это история про Иеронима как создателя глаголицы *глубоко неофициальная* и даже вредная антинаучная. Вообще история появления глаголицы покрыта мраком, есть даже версия, вполне обоснованная, что она появилась позже кириллицы. Может и нет, но уж никак не раньше VIII века.

Comment: На самом деле вы пересказали историю появления кириллицы, только все с ног на голову поставили. Обе буквы, Фита и Ферт, были добавлены в азбуку для передачи греческих буков, обозначающих звуки, которых не было у славян (как самостоятельных). На этом вся правда кончается. Ф -это не П с придыханием, ни в греческом, ни в русском. Это просто оглушенное В. И сам звук встречался а определенных позициях. Так что введение Ферта было вполне обосновано, никакие большевики на него не зарились.

Comment: "благодаря ... большевикам мы избавились от большинства ненужных букв (большевики токмо правописание изменили)" ======= Невнимательность, или здесь кто-то против большевиков! В любом случае, реформа Фортунатова-Шахматова готова была к реализации ещё в 1912 г., а задумывалась такой аж в XVIII в. Ломоносовым.

Comment: Вот доказательства того, что Иероним придумал глаголицу: есть латинская книга 1596 года в ней написано, естественно на латинском, что Иероним создатель этого письма. Вот книга (введёте в гугле): Alphabeta_et_Characteres 1596. И переведите на русский что там написано (думаю гугл переводчик справится). На странице 24 или если скачаете, то на 47